# PHP / Mysql -> Best way to make a indexed/categorized list

Tags: php, mysql, list, indexed

What i need to do is something like that:

Database:

```
name     |  category
---------|-----------
alan     |  foo
adam     |  foo
daniel   |  bar
mike     |  foobar
michael  |  foobar
```

To list like that:

```
FOO:
- Adam
- Alan

BAR:
- Daniel

FOOBAR:
- Michael
- Mike
```

So, i know i can make that list with a query litening the data with GROUP BY category (to to the headers), and than, making a query for each group, listening the names... But i was wondering is it possible to make that list with a single mysql query.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select group_concat(name) as names, category
from table_name
group by category`

You can split the names and list them after running the above query

Comment: Nice idea... That way i can run it in a single query... but in terms of performance, is it better to split every names field or have multiple queries?

Comment: Reducing database operations as much as possible would help improve an application's performance in general. So, I would go with the split method.